# Placing quotes around numeric text with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to place quotes around a text line if it starts with a number and no quotes (single or double). Examples:

```
123 ==> "123"

123: this is a line ==> "123": this is a line

this is a line with number 123 ==> this is a line with number 123

'this is a quoted line with single quotes' ==> 'this is a quoted line with single quotes'
```

Is there a sed way to do this?

Sorry - should also state there is a delimiter (:) between the number at the start and the rest of the line, so the quotes should only appear around the substring that is the number.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is line is just `5BC` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo '123 this is a line' | sed 's/^[0-9].*/"&"/g'
"123 this is a line"
$ echo '"123 this is a line"' | sed 's/^[0-9].*/"&"/g'
"123 this is a line"
```

Comment: No need to use `g` modifier here.